# contentpane extending below footer

Tags: asp.net, css

It looks like my contentpane is bigger than my page height. As a result, it is extending below the footer. Please help. I placed the contentpane inside a div.

Actually it is the table inside the div that is extending outside the div to below the footer

Comment: i have done that but it its still not working...

Comment: Then maybe give more information, just maybe.

Comment: put some code to investigate further..

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the z-index of your footer 0 and also placing it at the bottom using `bottom:0`